# How should REST-like API errors be handled in an Airflow hook?

Tags: airflow

While Airflow provides `AirflowException` and its derivatives, I'm curious how an error that occurs in a hook when talking to an external API should be handled? For example, say we have a REST-like API and are using `requests` to talk to this API--if our response object does not have a successful response, e.g. `response.ok == False`, we'd like to raise some kind of error (and in our specific, ideally ensure Sentry knows about it). We could create an `AirflowException` here and embed some meaningful context in our message, but this feels a little brittle and prone to losing context.

Answer (score 0):

Any exception that will happen in your code that you did not catch will be caught by Airflow and retry the task.

You can use `AirflowException` to raise a new error message. This is helpful when you want to change the error message.

A good example would be the `check_response` function in [HttpHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3aaf925d5898ab83dd4614bb69b4f1a789561f70/airflow/providers/http/hooks/http.py#L143:L156).

```
def check_response(self, response: requests.Response) -> None:
    """
    Checks the status code and raise an AirflowException exception on non 2XX or 3XX
    status codes
    :param response: A requests response object
    :type response: requests.response
    """
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        self.log.error("HTTP error: %s", response.reason)
        self.log.error(response.text)
        raise AirflowException(str(response.status_code) + ":" + response.reason)
```

Using Airflow exceptions provides a way to control over how the task will behave for example `AirflowFailException` can be used when you want to tell Airflow to fail the task immediately (ignoring the `retries` parameter)